# Get next item in a tree

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

Having a tree (logical in DB) with items in the form

> 1. List item A
> 2. List item B
>
>    1. List item C
>
>       1. List item D
> 3. List Item E
> 4. List Item F
>
>    1. List Item G

and so on (nesting depth not limited), I want to get the next node down (or up), starting from an arbitrary node.

Let's say, `List Item D` is given I want to write a function `GetNextNode()` that would return `List Item E`.

My idea would be to do some recursion stuff, but maybe there is a more clever way to handle this?

**My question:**

How would you solve this?

**EDIT 1:**

The tree can be accessed with functions like:

- `GetParentNode()`
- `GetChildrenNodes()`
- `GetNextSiblingNode()`
- etc.

So it's similar to e.g. e Windows Forms `TreeView`.

Comment: Are you asking how to store this in a database, do you have your items already in a TreeView on your form or how to create something like this in general?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how the structure of the tree is represented?

Comment: There are many **many** different ways of iterating through a tree - "tree traversal" as its called is a complicated subject. > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal < worth noting, tree structures and recursion go hand in hand, generally speaking you don't get one without the other.

Comment: @MattDavey I know this is a bit late :) But most tree operations can be done without recursion. This is a necessity on systems with limited stackspace and/or high cost-per-subroutine. Though if the recursion is on the tail of the subroutine a decent compiler can often optimize it away. Of course, the version employing recursion is often easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had to do this several times. From memory:

```
public Node GetBelowNode()
{
    if (GetChildrenNodes().count > 0)
        return GetChildrenNodes()[0];
    else
        if (GetNextSiblingNode() != null)
            return GetNextSiblingNode();
        else
        {
            Node curr = this;
            Node parent; 
            while (true)
            {
                parent = curr.GetParentNode();
                if (parent == null)
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    if (parent.GetNextSiblingNode() != null)
                        return parent.GetNextSiblingNode();
                    else
                        curr = parent;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this via recursion or... worst xD

I think there are only 3 basic cases:

```
private string getNext(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.FirstNode != null)
    {
        return node.FirstNode.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        if (node.NextNode != null)
        {
            return node.NextNode.Name;
        }
        else if (node.Parent.NextNode != null)
        {
            return node.Parent.NextNode.Name;
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

This doesn't works for every scenario. You should search the parent's next node too. Thanks to Vincent Vancalbergh for the comment ;-)

Comment: The nesting depth should be arbitrary.

Comment: FirstNode is the first of the child nodes, NextNode is the first "brother" after current node and Parent is the parent node ;-)

Comment: What about if the parent has no sibling but the grandfather has. Or the great-grandfather. Someone's voteup needs retracting..

Answer (score 1):

```
public Party Next {
    get {
        if (this.children.Count > 0) return this.children[0];

        Party target = this;
        do {
            if (target.NextSibling != null) return target.NextSibling;
        } while ((target = target.Parent) != null);

        return null;
    }
}

public Party Previous {
    get {
        if (Parent != null && Parent.children.Count > 0 && this == Parent.children[0]) {
            return Parent;
        }

        Party target = this;

        do {
            if (target.PreviousSibling != null) { target = target.PreviousSibling; break; }
        } while ((target = target.Parent) != null);

        if (target != null) {
            while (target.children.Count > 0) {
                target = target.children[target.children.Count - 1];
            }
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
TreeNode currentNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
treeView1.selectedNode = currentNode.NextNode;
```

Comment: This is for a `TreeView` tree (I have only a logical in-memory tree). In addition, your functions seems to work [for siblings only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextnode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since I got a great reply for the "down" part, I'll added my own "up" part. Maybe it is for some help of you; the up part is similar to:

> 1. Get the previous sibling.
> 2. If there *is* a previous sibling, get the deepest child node of this
>      sibling.
> 3. If there is *no* previous sibling, get the direct parent.

To get the deepest sibling (2.), I use the following code:

```
function getDeepestChild( page )
    dim result
    set result = nothing

    dim childPages
    set childPages = page.ChildPages

    if childPages.Count>0 then
        dim p
        set p = childPages(childPages.Count-1)
        ' recurse.
        set result = getDeepestChild( p )
    else
        set result = page
    end if

    set getDeepestChild = result
end function
```

(Yes, I do know that this is VBScript; I needed it in fact in this language)